# Different iterator behavior of raw array and std::array on clang++ and VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
bool greater_than_seven(int i) {
    return i > 5;
}
bool divisible_by_five(int x) {
    return ((x%5)==0);
}
int main() {
    int arr[]{3,6,9,12,15};
    std::cout<<"Enter a number you want to search: ";
    int num;
    std::cin>>num;
    auto result(std::find(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),num));
    if(result != std::end(arr))
        std::cout<<"arr contains: "<<num<<'\n';
    else
        std::cout<<"arr doesn't contain: "<<num<<'\n';

    for(result=std::find_if(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),greater_than_seven);result!=std::end(arr);++result)   
        std::cout<<*result<<' ';
    std::cout<<'\n';    
    std::array<int,4> x{33,66,99,55};
    for(result=std::find_if_not(std::begin(x),std::end(x),divisible_by_five);result!=std::end(x);++result)
        std::cout<<*result<<'\n';
}
```

This program compiles fine on g++ & clang++.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/OOA44723) ( g++ 5.4.0 )

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/VZNX44618) ( clang++ 3.8.0 )

But it gives horrible compiler error on Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.

See live demo [here](http://rextester.com/PXRU72581) ( Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64 )

```
Error(s):
source_file.cpp(27): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,4>' to 'int *'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
source_file.cpp(27): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
source_file.cpp(27): error C2679: binary '!=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,4>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(343): note: could be 'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(348): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\exception(353): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(388): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(395): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(402): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\system_error(409): note: or       'bool std::operator !=(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
source_file.cpp(27): note: while trying to match the argument list '(int *, std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,4>)'
        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]
```

So the question is which compiler is right here according to C++ standard ? Is this bug in VC++ compiler ?

Comment: This example is in no way a [mcve].  There is so much noise you could delete to get the same error.

Comment: @Yakk: I've clearly mentioned compiler versions & complete code. The code is complete & error is reproducible. What else do you want ?

Comment: What do you mean "horrible compiler error"? It says "cannot convert from `std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,4>` to `int *`". It doesn't get much more clear.

Comment: @Destructor You forgot "Minimal".

Comment: @Destructor See [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89bf2a7b227a5d67). Does it still reproduce the issue? If so, then the code in the question is far from Minimal.

Comment: @Angew: ok thank you. I'll post minimal code next time when I'll ask question here.

Comment: Have you turned on all warnings and compilance options in gcc and clang? I think they should certainly say something. The code is saying to assign an `iterator -> std::array<int,4>` to a variable of type `interator -> int[5]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is this bug in VC++ compiler ?

No.

You're assigning and comparing the iterators got from [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) on raw array (i.e. `result`, `std::find(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),num)`) and [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (i.e. `std::find_if_not(std::begin(x),std::end(x),divisible_by_five)` and `std::end(x)`), you might be supposing that the types of them are the same.

For raw arrays it'll be `T*`, i.e. `int*` for this case, this is guaranteed. The problem is that the standard doesn't specify the exact type of `std::array::iterator`, it just says it must satisfy the requirements of [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). Gcc and Clang choose the `int*` as its type, this is fine because the raw pointer satisfy the requirements. VC implements it as a customized class, this is fine too so long as the type satisfies the requirements. And note that that type doesn't have to be able to convert to `int*`; the standard doesn't require that at all.

So even your code works with Gcc and Clang, it's not guaranteed.

Comment: It is possible the OP didn't catch that `result` got a type from `std::begin( int(&)[5] )`(aka `int*`), then later is assigned/compared with the return value of `std::begin(std::array<int,4>&)` (an unspecified random access contiguous iterator in the standard, which is `int*` in clang but not in MSVC).  You might want to be more explicit about that.

Comment: Why standard doesn't specify the exact type of `std::array::iterator` ? Wouldn't it be better if standard had specified exact type of it ? This leads to code portability problems. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Destructor "This leads to code portability problems." If you don't use iterators got from different containers together like this (and you shouldn't), you should be fine. The standard doesn't specify the exact type of iterator of any containers.

Comment: @songyuanyao: ok thank you. So, if standard had specified the exact type of iterator of any container then it would be burden on standard library implementor & doing so would give no any important advantage. Right ?

Comment: @Destructor Yes. The standard specifies the concept and the details should be implementation issues. And the point is that on concept their types don't have to be the same.

Comment: @destructor in this case, iterator types are left unspecified so std library writers can innovate.  For example, debug checked iterators, or SCARY iterators, both woukd be impossible without that freedom unless the standard writer knew exactly what innovations would come in the future.